# How to get a docker container to update itself

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have this Java project that's inside a docker container and I push updates to Gitlab every once in a while. Gitlab takes care of building the docker image and pushing it to its container registry, but how would I update the container without having to SSH into the server?

Should I use the **CI/CD** to also update the container on my remote machine and how would I do that, or can I just **execute a docker-compose restart from inside the container** (I guess that won't work, because of how containers work, but maybe there is a way?).

I also found the **Java Docker API client**, but that would require me to open up the Docker API, which I would hate to do.

Comment: This is normally the point where one would use a container orchestration tool, e.g. kubernetes. Anyway, if you want to communicate with an API, you will have to do some authentication. For docker, you would have to pull the new image to the docker host and restart the deployment.

Comment: @Turing85 I might take a look at kubernetes later, but for now, how would I execute the commands to pull and restart the container? I won't need to authenticate because the repository is open, but I can't just execute shell commands from inside the container, right?

Comment: The authentication s not from the docker host to the repo, but from the CICD-pipeline to the dockere host. I would imagine that some kind of authentication is necessary, otherwise everyone with access to the docker API would be able to make requests? --- On the topic of what calls to make... I am not proficient in docker API usage, I am more of a kubernetes guy wrt. deployment. I use docker only locally for development.

Comment: So you would go the CI/CD route, where I would use Gitlabs pipelines to execute a script on my machine, that would pull the new container and restart it?

Comment: more like: the gitlab runner executes some script to communicate with the docker host so the docker host pulls the image and restarts the deployment, but yes.

Comment: Hm, ok that would probably be the easiest route. I was hoping for an option, where I wouldn't have to update to the latest version as soon as a pipeline is successful, but I might have to scrap that plan.

Comment: You do not have to. Gitlab CI supports [manual step](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#whenmanual), so you can "click to deploy".

Comment: Oh, that sounds awesome as well. Maybe I should go that route.

Comment: @Turing85 is correct. You can set the deployment to manual and make the deployments manually. On updating the docker image on your machine, you could use Gitlab secrets to store whatever authentication credentials you want to use to execute the update script/api on the machine that runs docker.

Comment: Yeah ok. I'm still wondering though if it would be possible to initiate the update process from the application. So that I could add a button to the interface and only if that's clicked the application get updated.